# WPF Change Visibility during design-time

Tags: wpf, visibility

My CustomControls UI element `Visibility` is bound through a BoolToVisibilityConverter, see code below :

```
<cc:CustomFFU LabelText="FFUZoneF_2-1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="55" Height="35" 
        InstanceAddress="MCS1.Cleanroom.ProcessCell.UN_ZonesF.EM_FFU.CM_FFU2_1" 
        Visibility="{Binding VisibilityFFUView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

The code works as it should, however during design-time the `visibility` is `Collapsed`. So every CustomControl on my window is not visible during development. Quite annyoning..

How is the visibility during `design-time` fixed to `Visibility`?
Ps. when I delete the BoolToVisibilityConverter, the status changes from Collapsed to Visible? Perhaps, because when designing the value represent false. Just a guess.

Comment: You did not show enough of your `View` xaml and its `DataContext` yet https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Visibilty Binding is pointless. UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: [Use Design Time Data with the XAML Designer in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you should add **d:Visibility="Visible"** property in xaml element that you want to be visible in design time

like this:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding Property}" d:Visibility="Visible" />
```

and make sure that you have **Ignorable="d"** from **"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"** namespace on your root xaml element
like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
add this --->   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
and this --->   mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This doesn't work in Rider wpf designer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The following error occors when I add the d:Visibility. The property "Visibility" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" namespace.

Comment: @AfronSall make sure that you have Ignorable="d" from "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" namespace. I expanded my answer

Comment: Thanks again. I already had both integrated, but still receiving the same error message. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @AfronSall try clean solution -> rebuild solution -> restart visual studio

Comment: d:IsHidden="False" is working. However, the object is still collapsed ofcourse. d:Visibility="Visible" doesn't seem to exists in Blend? Do you have a working sample?

Comment: @AfronSall yes here it is https://github.com/U7nk/d-Visibility-example/tree/main tested with visual studio 2019 community 16.11.14

Comment: Your help has been great so far. I accepted your answer as valid., because the git sample is working like it should. However, my project is using VS Framework 4.6.1., and for one reason not working. Do you know why?

Comment: d:IsHidden works, but can't use d:Visibilty. Do you have a working sample for VS Framework 4.6.1. as well?

Comment: @AfronSall looks like d:Visibility is not supported at net framework, but you can use another approach. Here is example for net framework 4.6.1 (working poorly on visual studio 2022, vs 19 is ok ) https://github.com/U7nk/d-Visibility-example/tree/main/NET%20Framework%204.6.1%20Example i will add it to answer later

Comment: Much appriciated! Thanks a lot, Kliment! It's working.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the way to solve “why vs2019 can't use `d:Visibility` directly”.
This is microsoft answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2019#troubleshooting

1. Design-time data requires Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7 or later.
2. Supports Windows desktop projects that target Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) for .NET Core and UWP. This feature is also available for .NET Framework in the Preview channel. To enable it, go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features`, select New WPF XAML Designer for .NET Framework and then restart Visual Studio.

When I selected New WPF XAML Designer for .Net Framework, I can use `d:Visibilty` and I haven't seen the error again!